# How to determine a string that needs to be UTF8 decoded

Tags: php

Is there a possibility that you can check a string if it needs to be UTF8 decoded in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) to check if the string is already encoded in UTF-8:

```
mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true)
```

This returns *false* if the string is not valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if the string is using UTF-8 encoding by using

```
 mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
```